# How to call google api service using

Tags: iphone, ios, get

i am new in iOS 
I want to call google api direction service, and parse it, i know how to call web service by using post method, but i don't know how to integrate parameters into url, and get json response from that.
please help me.

Comment: Are you looking for `[NSString stringWithFormat:]`?

Comment: check this link http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/how-to-implement-core-location-and-the-google-xml-weather-api-on-the-iphone/ my be it help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the below code, you will get some idea.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSString *stringOrigin = @"Surandai";
    NSString *stringDestination = @"Coimbatore";
    NSData *dataDirection = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%@&destination=%@&sensor=true", stringOrigin, stringDestination]]];
    NSDictionary *dictionaryDirection = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataDirection options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"dictionaryDirection - %@", dictionaryDirection);
        //Do UI update here
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Paramasivan Samuttiram, but there is problem, my origin and destination are multiple words, i.e. they having space between them (e.g. 34 st penn station), what is solution for this ?

Comment: Use  stringByAddingPercentageEscapesUsingEncoding method.

Answer (score 1):

For passing data using `NSURLConnection` Post you can use `setHTTPBody` method.

You can use the following code:

```
NSURL *aUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"yourURL"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:aUrl
                                         cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                     timeoutInterval:60.0];

NSURLConnection *connection= [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request 
                                                             delegate:self];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *postString = @"username=Midhun&password=Midhun";
[request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

And the respond data can be get through `didReceiveData` delegate method. You need to append the received data to a `NSMutableData` object for further use.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{ 
   [receivedData appendData:data];
}
```